# something like confirm("Are U sure?") JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, modal-dialog, confirm

I use

`string js = @" return confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?');";
 myAspButton.OnClientClick = js;`

event rises after "OK" clicking and nothing happen after "Cancel"

I want to create my custom modal, but server event fired before any button click!

how to implement my own function like `confirm(Are you sure you want to do this?')` which returns value after button click?

my code:

```
string js = @"dialog('Are you sure you want to do this?',
            function() {
                        return true;
                    },
            function() {
                        return false;
                    }
        );";

        myAspButton.OnClientClick = js;
```

JS code:

```
    function dialog(message, yesCallback, noCallback) {
        $('.title').html(message);
        var dialog = $('#modal_dialog').dialog();

        $('#btnYes').click(function() {
            dialog.dialog('close');
            yesCallback();
        });
        $('#btnNo').click(function() {
            dialog.dialog('close');
            noCallback();
        });
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<div id='modal_dialog'>
<div class='title'>
</div>
<input type='button' value='yes' id='btnYes' />
<input type='button' value='no' id='btnNo' />
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some modifications to make on your code...
You cannot bind a `click` event many times on the same element or it will trigger many times, so first you need to remove the bind to add it again with another callback.

Also, you can make an "overlay", that covers the entire page until some button is clicked. See the `css` part to take a look on what I did.

See the example below and check if this it's something you need.

```js
$("#dialogBtn").on("click", dialog.bind(this, 'Are you Sure?', yesCallback, noCallback));

function dialog(message, yesCallback, noCallback) {
      var modal = $("#modal_dialog");
      modal.show();
      $('.title').html(message);
            
      $('#dialogBtnYes').off("click").on("click", function() {
           modal.hide()
           yesCallback.call();
      });
      $('#dialogBtnNo').off("click").on("click", function() {
            modal.hide()
            noCallback.call();
      });
}

function yesCallback(){
  console.log("YES");
}
function noCallback(){
  console.log("NO");
}
```

```css
#modal_dialog{
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);  
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;  
  left: 0;
}

#modal-content{
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Dialog' id="dialogBtn"/>

<div id='modal_dialog'>
  <div id="modal-content">
    <div class='title'></div>
    <input type='button' value='yes' id='dialogBtnYes' />
    <input type='button' value='no' id='dialogBtnNo' />
  </div>
</div>
```